# Creating a recipe for a CMake project that finds its dependencies with find_package

Tags: conan

I want to make a Conan package for a project I found on Github.  This project is a CMake project and depends on openssl.  The project finds openssl with a normal find_package.

My recipe declares the openssl dependency obviously, but where I struggle is how do I get the find_package(openssl) inside the project's CMake to find the openssl obtained by Conan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [cmake_find_package](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/cmake_find_package.html) generator.

```py
from conans import ConanFile

class Foo(ConanFile):
    requires = "openssl/1.1.1l"
    generators = "cmake", "cmake_find_package"

    ...
```

This will generate `Findxxx.cmake` for all your dependencies.

If you are creating packages for your first time, I suggest you reading [how to create a package](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/getting_started.html) from official docs, and the best practices from [Conan Center Index](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/docs/how_to_add_packages.md#how-to-provide-a-good-recipe).

UPDATE: Using `CMakeDeps`

Many improvements have been made for Conan 2.0, including a new approach for generators. The [CMakeDeps](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake/cmakedeps.html) is new way to go when needing `xxx-config.cmake`. It's not documented on getting started yet, but its reference brings a very straightforward example.